# Factorial Series I

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function

Given the factorial series
\begin{align}
\beta_{1}(x) = \sum_{s=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{s} \, s!}{x(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+s)}
\end{align}
then what are the coefficients, $a_{s}$, of the square of $\beta_{1}(x)$,
\begin{align}
[ \beta_{1}(x)]^{2} = \sum_{s=1}^{\infty} \frac{s! \, a_{s}}{x(x+1)(x+2) \cdots (x+s)}.
\end{align}
I speculate that the coefficients are a finite series of the form
\begin{align}
a_{m} = \sum_{r=1}^{m} b_{r}.
\end{align}

Comment: standard cauchy product leads nowhere?

Comment: @Leucippus It is possible to write the series in terms of the hypergeometric function $\,_{2}F_{1}\left(1,1;x+1;-1\right).$ Maybe there is some useful identity.